# Android app is shown as not compatible in play store

Tags: android, google-play, simple-framework

I have published a new update of my App. After publishing it got a warning like "Warning: Your active APK supports less devices then the previous APK. Some users won't get the update."

So i've compared the details of the current and the prior APK. There is only one difference: The new one has the additional entry "Native Platform: simple-xml.2.6.9.jar".

Do you think that there is a problem with it? Acutally i've intergrated the .jar into my android project.

[image: details of the app]

Additionally, the developer console shows me that the app is now compatible with 0 devices... if i search for a certain device i get a notice that it's because of my manifest settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.kit.aifb.nukit"
android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="@string/app_versionName" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.KIT.Styled"
    android:allowBackup="true" >    

    <activity
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.ChooseCourseActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.QuestioningAndVotingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.AnswerQuestionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.ShowResultsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.ImpressumActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.LicensesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.survey.SurveyListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.survey.QuestionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".SurveyListActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SurveyListActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="edu.kit.aifb.nukit.gui.survey.SurveyResultsActivity"
        android:label="SurveyResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".SurveyListActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SurveyListActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

if i install the apk directly on my device, it works fine.

Comment: Does `simple-xml.2.6.9.jar` have some associated JNI library?

Comment: Mh i don't know, how can i figure it out?

Comment: What is in your `libs/` directory?

Comment: my `libs/` directory contains:

`ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar`,
`simple-xml-2.6.9.jar` and `SurveyLib.jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i fixed it.

The problem was that actualy only the SurveyLib.jar is using simple-xml-2.6.9.jar and the simplexml.jar was included within the SurveyLib.jar. So i think there was a problem dexing the simplexml.jar within surveylib.jar.

i've created the surveylib.jar again without simplexml.jar but included the simplexml.jar to the libs folder of my app.

now it works fine. thanks to you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be due to changes done in your Android Manifest relating to max and min sdk versions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

If this SDK version range has been altered, your new updated app might support lesser number of devices.

Comment: the `minSdkVersion` is the same as in the prior apk. Just the `targetSdkVersion` got updated to the most current one (17)